# How to merge the results of a number of cells in excel, so that a yes in any one of the input cells will evaluate to yes in a single output cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
yes     no      no      no
no      yes     no      no
no      no      no      no
no      no      no      no
```

How can I combine these results so that Col5 will equal "yes" if there is a "yes" in any of the cells in Col1-4 and only equal "no" if every cell in a row from col1-4 equals "no"?

So in this example the output should look like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
yes     no      no      no      yes
no      yes     no      no      yes
no      no      no      no      no
no      no      no      no      no
```

(I am using a mac with Excel version 15.29)

Comment: Or() worksheet function

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:D2,"yes")=0,"no","yes")
```

Comment: @BenJeffrey, did you try this solution?

Comment: @BenJeffrey, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to people trying at helping you

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward `IF` with `OR` :

```
=IF(OR(A1="yes";B1="yes";C1="yes";D1="yes");"yes";"no")
```

or

```
=IF(OR(A1="yes",B1="yes",C1="yes",D1="yes"),"yes","no")
```

Comment: Why semicolons?

Comment: @SMeaden : Isn't it the default in Excel? I have both English and French versions with respective OS Languages and this is what I use in every worksheet functions.

Comment: Ok if it works for you, I'd had thought commas, tant pis.

Comment: Ha, nice edit, also OP could use true false and format as yes no

Comment: @SMeaden : I added the comma's version! I only use commas when I'm using the functions in VBA, but in Excel, I always have semicolons!

Comment: @SMeaden : haha! Don't ask to much of the OP, he clearly is just starting to use Excel!^^